# Angularjs variable doesn't change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

while in console we see that it changed? http://jsfiddle.net/LCZfd/1006/

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($document) {
    let scope=this;
    this.current=0;

    this.isCurrent=function(val){
        return val==this.current;
    }
    this.selectCurrent=function(val){
        this.current=val;
    }
    $document.on('keypress', keyupHandler);
    function keyupHandler(keyEvent) {
        scope.selectCurrent(keyEvent.key-1);
        console.log(scope.current);
    } 
});
```

Open the console and you will see that variable changed its value. I just want to use keyboard in my app.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this scope.selectCurrent(keyEvent.key-1); key is a property which returns a alphabet and you are subtracting 1 from it????

Comment: Little trouble here `return val==this.current;`, the `this` on this context belongs the function `isCurrent` not the controller it self, you may use your cached variable `scope` like `return val == scope.current;` instead.

Comment: your code seem to produce a warning about the module, maybe that's a reason it doesn't work

Comment: On your first line you set a named reference to `this` but then you don't use it. Try replacing all your references to `this` with the named reference. By the way, 'scope' is not a good idea for the named reference to `this` in this context because `this` is actually your controller instance. Name it 'ctrl' or 'myCtrl' or something that won't cause it to be confused with a proper AngularJS scope object.

Comment: Also, you are trying to subtract a number from `keyEvent.key` but that property is not numeric, so you're assigning NaN to your `current` property.

Comment: @J.C. he's trying to use the numpad i guess, to "select" the divs i think

Comment: @Kaddath u r right!

Comment: @JCFord The problem is that he can't change controller variable inside the handler

Answer (score 1):

this is quite simple but i had forgotten that. If you use events that are external to angular's refresh cycle, it's not applied. This will work like this, but it's not recommended, because if you try to apply while in a digesting cycle, this will cause an error. You should read the docs to find a solution to stay in the borders of angular:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($document, $rootScope) {
    let scope=this;
    this.current=0;

    this.isCurrent=function(val){
        return val==this.current;
    }
    this.selectCurrent=function(val){
        this.current=val;
    }
    $document.on('keypress', keyupHandler);
    function keyupHandler(keyEvent) {
        //the apply:
        $rootScope.$apply(scope.selectCurrent(keyEvent.key-1));
        console.log(scope.current);
    } 
});
```